# Ошибка при запуске программы на Си в Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    char buffer[50]; 
    int a = 10, b = 20, c; 
    c = a + b; 
    sprintf(buffer, "Sum of %d and %d is %d", a, b, c); 

    printf("%s", buffer); 

    return 0; 
}
```

При запуске данной программы Visual Studio выдает ошибку сборки решения, хотя этот же код отлично работает в Code::Blocks. В чем ошибка? Или же проблемы в настройке VS, если это так, подскажите, что нужно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, вам пишут (и вы должны приводить в вопросе эти сообщения!)

> `warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.`

Т.е. вам говорят - что вы используете небезопасную функцию. Тут же предлагают целых два решения: или использовать безопасную функцию `sprintf_s()`, или - если вы настаиваете на использовании небезопасной функции - определить в начале программы

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Выбор за вами.

P.S. Выбор - приводить ли **все** сообщения об ошибках - у вас нет. Если сказали "А" - *Visual Studio выдает ошибку сборки решения*, то говорите и "Б" - *какую именно*.